# WPF: Update a label in a listbox item

Tags: wpf, label, controltemplate, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` where the number of items is added based on and integer property set by a user. The items are created from a `ControlTemplate` resource that which is comprised of a Label and a `TextBox` inside of a `DockPanel`. The label is not data bound but I would like for it to have somewhat dynamic content based on the (index + 1) of the `ListboxItem` for which it is contained. My question/problem is that I want to be able update the content of the label for each `ListboxItem`, but cannot access the label for some reason. I am unaware of any way to do this through data-binding of the label since the label is in a template and has no knowledge that it has a parent that is a `ListboxItem`. Can anyone help me clear up some of these confusions to get me back on the right track, please?

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <DockPanel Background="Transparent" Height="28" Name="playerDockPanel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Label Name="playerNameLabel" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Player"></Label>
        <TextBox Height="23" Width ="150" Name="playerName" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I would like to be able to bind the content of the `Label` in xaml, or update the content of the `Label` in the code behind. I'm not sure what the best route would be.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Initially I was trying to find the `Label` in the template like this....

```
  Label label = (Label)lbi.Template.FindName("playerNameLabel",lbi);
```

I found out that you have to call `ApplyTemplate()` in order to build the template's visual tree before it will be able to find the element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `IMultiValueConverter` that will get the index of your template:

```
public class PositionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ItemsControl itemsControl = value[0] as ItemsControl;
        UIElement templateRoot = value[1] as UIElement;
        if (templateRoot != null)
        {
            UIElement container = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(itemsControl, templateRoot) as UIElement;
            if (container != null)
            {
                return itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You should then use the converter into your `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
    <DockPanel Background="Transparent" Height="28" Name="playerDockPanel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Label Name="playerNameLabel" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="{Binding Title}"></Label>
        <Label Height="23" Width ="150" Name="playerName" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Label.Content>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource positionConverter}">
                    <!-- The ItemsControl-->
                    <Binding ElementName="listBox" />
                    <!-- The root UIElement-->
                    <Binding ElementName="playerDockPanel"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Content>                    
        </Label>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```